# Any free or paid software for graphical drawing of Robotics Kinematic Scheme?

Tags: kinematics

I have been searching for days looking for a dedicated software for easily draw kinematic diagrams of robotics like this:

[image]

I came by [this software](http://alexdu.github.io/sketch-lib/) but it is a bit hard to grasp. Is there any GUI based software instead?

Comment: The standard way of representing a robot is the DH parameters. Once you have those, you do not need a GUI and can use things like Matlab's  robotics toolbox.

Comment: There is a robot arm kinematic GUI application installed on the Fedora Robotics Spin.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* wbadry, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site, and that includes shopping for recommendations. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.